# Backspace in insert mode in vi doesn't erase the character

Tags: vi

I am new to vi, actually I have started learning vi from today and I have got stuck at the behavior of the backspace key.

Actually when I fired up vi on my Ubuntu 12.04 for the first time my backspace key was working normally but after that it has started behaving strangely. Whenever I press the backspace in the insert mode it just moves one place to the left instead of erasing the character.

How can I get back the default backspace functionality? Please note that I don't want to install vim or set nocompatibilty.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That's correct behavior for vi, and it does erase the character, it just doesn't show it by replacing it with a blank like in vim. It will be apparent when you overwrite the erased character with another character, or switch back to command mode.

E.g. starting with command mode on an empty line, the following will result in the line containing `fo`:

<kbd>i</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

Before you hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, the line will read `foo`, but the last `o` has been tagged as an "erase-column". See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html#tag_20_152_13_88 (mainly point 4 under that heading, and also browse a little further down to read about <Control>-H)

Comment: I spent at least couple of hours trying to figure this out (at times cursing my Windows terminal app too), finally it worked. Thank you! 

Answer (score 90):

Here is the simplest solution.
Open a terminal, go to home directory and type

```
vi .vimrc
```

a new file open now add these lines to the file and exit by saving

```
$ set nocompatible
$ set backspace=2
```

Comment: The OP mentioned that they don't want to use `nocompatibility`

Comment: there is no need for no compatability u can also do it just by addig the second line

Comment: Second line only works for me if I also add the first line.

Comment: Started from an empty .vimrc and wondered why backspace didn't work on mac in iTerm2. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @minerz029 add yet this is the answer most people are here for, since there was no such qualification in the page title.

Comment: I'm on OpenSUSE and adding `set backspace=2` to `~/.vimrc` solved the issue for me :)

Answer (score 34):

You need to change to the "insert" mode by moving the cursor with `i`.
There are other ways to delete characters directly. 
You can download a powerpoint that I use when teaching a class on VI [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8JoV2w_9hicMHBzNHl2OXRwMEk/edit?usp=sharing).

It sounds like you are in the "Command" mode. 
To move your cursor: 
`H` = Left, `J` = Up, `K` = Down,  `L` = Right

Once you have your cursor positioned you can **delete** text as follows:
`x`  Deletes the character **under** the cursor
`X`  Deletes the character **before** the cursor
`dw` Deletes from the cursor **to the next word**
`dd` Deletes the **line** the cursor is on.

To **enter text**, you can use one of the text entry modes. 
`a` Adds text to the **right** of the cursor
`A` Adds text to the **end** of the current line
`i` Adds text to the **left** of the cursor
`I` Adds test to the **beginin** of the current line
`o` Opens a new line **below** the current line and places you in text entry mode
`O` Opens a new line **Above** the current line and places you in text entry mode

To exit Text entry mode, and return to the Command mode, use `Esc`.

To **Undo** changes: (A student favorite)
`u` Undo the **last command** entered
`U` Undo **all changes** to the ** current line**

To Save/Quit:
`:w` Writes (Saves) the file and remains open
`:wq` Writes (Saves) the file and **exits** VI
`:q` Quits (Exits) **if you've made no changes**
`:q!` Quits (Exits) **without saving** changes
`ZZ` Writes (Saves) the file and **exits** VI  (same as `:wq`)

Comment: The OP mentioned that the mysterious behavior occurs *in insert mode*. So this is not the answer to the question asked.

Comment: Actually the OP did not state *in insert mode*. The question was edited.

Comment: Ok. You're correct. It looks like I made an assumption. It's been my experience that most people new to VI run into issues with switching modes, and navigating when in the command mode. My students often complain and blame VI for a having erratic behaviour when it's simply user error, or not having a grasp of the command set.

Comment: Understandable. I agree that is the common reaction to non-insert-mode.

Comment: Argus, "in insert mode" was added to the question title in an edit, but it was in the body of the question from the beginning.

Comment: I always get annoyed by not being able to use an `i` from the last position when I want to append something else to the line.  I know `a` exists, but I always seem to do `i`, then remember, hit `esc` and then `a`

Comment: @Argusvision - "blame VI" - you say that as if you don't think there's an issue with vi. Why does running apt-get update cause the behavior to change then? That tells me the old behavior was recognized as an error - the only question is why modern distros come with a buggy version of vi.

Comment: any suggestion on how can I delete a `new line` char before the cursor? The `X` command doesn't deletes a `new line` char before the cursor.

Answer (score 24):

Install the full vim package to get the backspace and arrow key functionality

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Comment: It's working  as expected.. Best answer

Comment: That is the perfect answer. No need to edit any config files, just install the `vim-runtime` package and everything works as I am used to. Thanks!

Comment: After installing vim ; vi is now working good. Thanks