# Hitting arrow keys adds characters in vi editor

Tags: text-editor, vi

When I tried to use arrow keys in insert mode in `vi` editor the following characters are being inserted in the editor:

- for <kbd>↓</kbd> I get B,
- for <kbd>↑</kbd> I get A,
- for <kbd>←</kbd> I get D,
- for <kbd>→</kbd> I get C.

Please help me in resolve this problem.

Comment: I had a good laugh reading the title ;) I'm sure there is an XKCD for the spooky feeling that comes (to novice users) when arrow key prints letters.

Comment: It is very very scary ;)

Comment: It seems it's done on purpose in vim's code to mimic the behaviour of old vi, so my question would be: What was actually the point of the old vi having the arrow keys writing the letters ABCD on the document you're trying to insert text in instead of just moving the cursor? What's the actual "useful" use case for that?! I just can't fathom the reason for that.

Comment: @OMA every time I set up a new Linux instance I wonder the same thing... and I have to Google to figure out how to fix it. why on earth is this still the default setting.

Comment: I had this *exact* same problem and solved it, but `askubuntu` won't allow me to answer b/c it's a "highly active question".

Answer (score 355):

If you don't already have a `.vimrc` file in your home directory, create one using this:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

Add this line to the top of the file:

```
set nocompatible
```

Save the file and this should fix the problem for you. :)

Comment: I had to create a .exrc file for vi, but set nocompatible worked great.

Comment: There is a trick if you use `vi` instead of `vim`, you have to do the same configuration but in the `~/.exrc` file.

Comment: Worked. But why this fix is required? Why by default it does not handle arrows?

Comment: By default, vi/vim is programmed to replace arrow keys with the keys h, j, k, l. This is done so you dont have to move from the major key area of the keyboard.

Comment: next problem is backspace, solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/296385/backspace-in-insert-mode-in-vi-doesnt-erase-the-character

Comment: @Locane This isn't a Solaris thing, it's a VIM thing. It doesn't matter if you're on Solaris, Linux, UNIX, Windows, BSD--VIM always starts in Vi-compatible mode by default.

Comment: @tzi I use vi, not vim, but this ~/.vimrc change worked for me, too.

Comment: @Max_Williams It is possible that vi is aliased on your system to invoke vim.  I have seen that before.

Comment: None of the answers here works for me on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I get this error when I start vi after using both the .exrc fix: `compatible: No such option - 'set all' gives all option values Error detected in .exrc.[Hit return to continue]` 
I am using: Version SVR4.0, Solaris 2.5.0

Comment: This answer could be improved by including an explanation of why `set nocompatible` works or what it does.

Comment: According to `:help compatible` `set nocompatible` is already implicitly applied if you have `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your terminal for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Didn't work for me, though my problem was slightly different.  In my case hitting the arrow keys did _nothing at all_.  Had to `set term=builtin_ansi` to fix it.

Comment: The answer states creating a `~/.vimrc`. But when you are within a vi/vim session already, you can also just press Esc and type `:set nocompatible` or any of the other suggested options in the comments

Answer (score 188):

Installing the `vim` package will fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

There are many good vim/vi tutorials on YouTube, or the web generally.
For your problem, see the article [8 Essential Vim Editor Navigation Fundamentals](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/8-essential-vim-editor-navigation-fundamentals/).

Then continue to open files as usual:

```
vi desired-file
```

Comment: worked for me -- though not sure why this is different from the vim I was launching previously

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (but seems like no one is accepting). it's the simplest/cleanest way to get vim fully 'modernized' to a computer console (instead of tty/ANSI era terminals.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm surprised that raspian comes with the version of vi/vim that it does... although all the tutorials for it tell you to use nano, which it's hard to argue that vim is really better than it. Probably the only reason I use vim rather than nano is because vim is always on every machine and it seems like a 50/50 chance whether nano is.

Comment: This did not work for me on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Fixed, worked for me on RaspberryPI while connected using putty. Thanks!

Comment: Wish I'd done this earlier. Installing vim also automatically gives syntax highlighting to most standard code files that you open with `vi xxx` (which is a huge plus).

Comment: Agreed this should be considered the best most straightforward answer.

Answer (score 29):

With `vi`, when pressing <kbd>i</kbd> you activate the command to **Insert** text.
This command allows you to insert text in your file. 
And right, when:

- pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> it will insert a "A",
- pressing <kbd>↓</kbd> it will insert a "B",
- ...

**Till** you deactivate this command.
To deactivate a command in `vi`: just press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
And then you will get back normal use of your arrow keys:

- <kbd>↑</kbd> to go up,
- <kbd>↓</kbd> to go down,
- ...

---

FYI, here are some `vi` commands:
<sub>From this [source](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html).</sub>

`:x`<kbd>Return</kbd> **quit vi**, writing out modified file to file named in original invocation
`:wq`<kbd>Return</kbd> **quit vi**, writing out modified file to file named in original invocation
`:q`<kbd>Return</kbd> **quit (or exit) vi**
`:q!`<kbd>Return</kbd> **quit vi** even though latest changes have not been saved for this vi call

<kbd>↓</kbd> **move** cursor down one line
<kbd>↓</kbd> **move** cursor up one line
<kbd>←</kbd> **move** cursor left one character
<kbd>→</kbd> **move** cursor right one character

`u` **undo** whatever you just did; a simple toggle
`.` **redo** whatever you just did

`i` **insert** text before cursor, until <kbd>Esc</kbd> hit
`I` **insert** text at beginning of current line, until <kbd>Esc</kbd> hit
`a` **append** text after cursor, until <kbd>Esc</kbd> hit
`A` **append** text to end of current line, until <kbd>Esc</kbd> hit
`o` **open** and put text in a new line below current line, until <kbd>Esc</kbd> hit
`O` **open** and put text in a new line above current line, until <kbd>Esc</kbd> hit

`r` **replace** single character under cursor (no <kbd>Esc</kbd> needed)
`cw` **change** the current word with new text,starting with the character under cursor, until <kbd>Esc</kbd> hit
`x` **delete** single character under cursor
`Nx` **delete** N characters, starting with character under cursor
`dw` **delete** the single word beginning with character under cursor
`C` **change** (replace) the characters in the current line, until <kbd>Esc</kbd> hit
`D` **delete** the remainder of the line, starting with current cursor position

`dd` **delete** entire current line
`Ndd` **delete** N lines, beginning with the current line;  e.g., 5dd deletes 5 lines
`yy` **copy** (yank, cut) the current line into the buffer
`Nyy` **copy** (yank, cut) the next N lines, including the current line, into the buffer
`p` **paste** the line(s) in the buffer into the text after the current line

`0` (zero) **move** cursor to start of current line (the one with the cursor)
`$` **move** cursor to end of current line
`w` **move** cursor to beginning of next word
`b` **move** cursor back to beginning of preceding word
`:0`<kbd>Return</kbd> or `1G` **move** cursor to first line in file
`:n`<kbd>Return</kbd> or `nG` **move** cursor to line n
`:$`<kbd>Return</kbd> or `G` **move** cursor to last line in file

`/string` **search** forward for occurrence of string in text
`?string` **search** backward for occurrence of string in text
`n` **move** to next occurrence of search string
`N` **move** to next occurrence of search string in opposite direction

Comment: Arrow key down inserting "B" is not an expected behavior. Arrow keys should be moving cursors up and down/ left and right regardless of the insert mode.

Comment: @JamesWong Actually, it _is_ expected behavior, as that is how Vi was originally programmed. VIM, (unofficially) the successor to Vi, is in Vi-compatible mode by default, which includes this behavior for the arrow keys. So the word "should" here is merely subjective, as VIM is actually doing what it was purposefully programmed to do.

Comment: @villapx - No, it isn't expected behavior. Expected behavior is defined by what your typical user expects. The typical person using vi/vim is using it because that's what's installed on a server that they need to quickly configure and they won't be doing enough to bother with installing something else. Few actually choose to use vim when given an option, and fewer actually know all these features or quirks. The typical user expects arrows to move the cursor - that is the expected behavior. Anything else is unexpected behavior, and should be written up as a bug for how unexpected it is.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare You're free to define "expected" however you choose. I'm defining it as what's expected by the author of the code, as they were quite clear in the VIM manual how this is supposed to behave...from `:help compatible`: "By default this option is on and the Vi defaults are used for the options. This default was chosen for those people who want to use Vim just like Vi, and don't even (want to) know about the 'compatible' option."

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Basically, the VIM author clearly had a specific audience in mind when writing this portion of the code, and just because that audience is different from what _your_ audience would be, doesn't mean it's a bug. You can file it as a bug if you wish, but be prepared to be berated by VIM fundamentalists (and really anyone who respects the 'manual', a la RTFM aficionados).

Comment: @villapx : OK, so it's done on purpose to mimic the behaviour of old "vi", so my question would be: What was actually the point of the old "vi" having the arrow keys writing the letters ABCD on the document you're trying to insert text in instead of just moving the cursor? What's the actual "useful" use case for that?!

Comment: @OMA it's not "writing the letters ABCD"; every key on your keyboard sends a specific sequence of binary bits to the computer, which your terminal emulator forwards to the program running within it. It's then the program's job to interpret those bits into something. Vi is _old_ (literally came out in 1976), and computers/terminals back then used totally different sequences of bits for the different non-alpha keys than today's keyboards do. The original Commodore 64 (1982) didn't even _have_ arrow keys, for example. So one can imagine why Vi doesn't properly support today's arrow keys.

Comment: @villapx : Thanks for the explanation. My next question would then be: What's the point of modern vi/vim in perfectly emulating such old behaviour which doesn't make sense in nowadays computers? Modern Linux distros are usually used with modern computers (at least computers from THIS CENTURY!), so why do some Linux distros write ABCD in vi instead of moving the cursor, which is what any sensible person would expect of the arrow keys?

Comment: @OMA No problem. VIM is also old: it was first released in 1991. Perhaps the most impressive thing about VIM is its backwards compatibility, meaning if you wrote some .vimrc entries way back in 1997, they'd still work today. Hence the fact that `compatible` mode is still defaulted to "on". For those that want a powerful VIM-like editor but more modern and with much less emphasis on compatibility with things from the '70s, there's [Neovim](https://neovim.io/). Bonus, Neovim [defaults to non-Vi-compatible mode](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/1622/commits)

Comment: I didn't know about that editor, but I'm sure it's very competent and powerful. The problem is, it's not included stock with Linux distros! The sole reason I might use vi is because it's the only editor available when I'm connecting to a remote Linux server, so if I have to install another third party editor (which I might not have permissions for) then it's useless to me no matter how good it actually is. I still can't comprehend why an ANCIENT editor from 1976 is the only text editor that comes stock with all Linux distros, server or desktop, instead of a more modern text-only alternative.

Answer (score 24):

To disable printing letters on pressing arrows in edit mode you can do following

```
vi $HOME/.exrc
```

(create file if it does not exist) and then add line `set nocompatible` to it and save.

Comment: I put that in .vimrc. Why do you put it in .exrc?

Comment: Vim sources both - see output of `:version` for load order (also `:h .exrc` or `:h init`). I suppose someone might want a setting to apply in both vi and vim, or could be sheer force of habit.

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER

Comment: If running `vi` with `sudo`, the line should be added to `/root/.exrc`.

Answer (score 11):

There are three modes in vi editor namely:

- command mode
- input mode
- default mode.

When youu open a file, you are in default mode. Now if you want to go to a specific position in your text, just use arrow keys or use <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> keys. Note that this would work only when you have not pressed <kbd>i</kbd> (or any other input mode entering command like <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>).

The reason for 'B' may be because the arrow keys in input mode don't function as arrow keys, so just press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go into default mode any time. When to shift to input mode press <kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>a</kbd>, and to navigate just press <kbd>i</kbd> key and use arrow keys or <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same Problem but not only on my local machine but also on connections via putty on a sles machine in a Win7 VM over a citrix receiver. Both the local host and the remote hosts show after a reinstall of Ubuntu had the exact same problem.

After finding out that

```
$ localectl list-keymaps 
Couldn't find any console keymaps.
```

Causes this strange VI behaviour I installed the package console-data which solves the issue!

```
sudo apt-get install console-data
```

Answer (score 6):

*Here is an explanation*:

**Vi** is an editor that's been around a long while, with roots back to the Unix systems. It's a good tool but it has been iterated on and now there is better. **Vim** was written later and is that iteration. People commonly refer to vi as 'vim-minimal' and to vim is an "improved" version of vi. You can think of it like this: vi is the core and vim expands on it.

*Likely how you discovered the behavior*:

In order for you to have discovered this problem, you pressed "**i**" to enter into **insert** mode and then used your arrow keys to navigate the correct line and edit point. This is what caused your unexpected char issue.

*Solution 1 or 2*

1. `vi someFile` While using **vi**, first move to the edit point, then enter into insert mode.
2. `vim someFile` Simply use **vim** from the start.

I cannot stress enough to read the manual (man pages) or to use -h for help. Once you adjust to the patterns in the shell, man pages become your best friend. Example: `man vi` or `man vim`

---

*Validate that Vim is installed*.

Open a console window and execute:

`dpkg --list | grep vim`

If you get something similar to this, then you can just start using vim.

```
~ $ dpkg --list | grep vim
ii  vim         2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3  amd64  Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
ii  vim-common  2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3  amd64  Vi IMproved - Common files
ii  vim-runtime 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3  all    Vi IMproved - Runtime files
ii  vim-tiny    2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3  amd64  Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version
```

If the command prompt returns with nothing, then vim is is not installed. Use the below examples to update your repositories and then install vim.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

On the off chance that you use vi or vim only when searching on the internet how to fix something and you happen to forget to type `vim`, there is one way that you can fix it for the future. I caution you to pay attention. You can use an alias to overwrite vi with a reference to vim so that no matter what you type in the infrequent future, you get vim without that "oops!" moment. You can always delete an alias later.

Type `vim .bashrc`. Move down to the empty line with only a `~` (or to any other line that starts with `alias` (so they're grouped together) and then press the *i* key to enter -insert- mode. On its own separate line, enter the following:

```
alias vi='vim'
```

Press `Esc` and then type `:wq`. Now you need to reload the file. Type `source .bashrc` Any other shell that opens after you have made these edits will automatically load the .bashrc file.

Answer (score 5):

This can also be due to the `TERM` variable; set it for example like this:

```bash
export TERM=xterm
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me where the other answers didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

All the explanations given are a bit bizarre. I have vi but not vim installed.

Checking alternatives: `/etc/alternatives/vi` → `/usr/bin/vim.tiny`

So `vi` is `vim.tiny`, and it uses `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny`.

And in `vimrc.tiny` you find the following line:

```
set compatible
```

Which is almost the only thing in this file. Note that in `/etc/vim/vimrc` it is using `nocompatible`.

So either install vim, or change the `vimrc.tiny` file, or create your own `~/.vimrc` which should contain the line:

```
set nocompatible
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's so bizarre. You end up suggesting 1. install Vim - http://askubuntu.com/a/220072/158442, 2. creating `~/.vimrc` and setting `nocompatible`: http://askubuntu.com/a/353944/158442, or 3. editing a system file. Only the suggestion to edit `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny` is new, and yet you call answers bizarre while suggesting the same thing as them.

Comment: I agree with Gunstick.  Other answers go off on how they use vi, without directly telling user what to do to make arrow keys work. Other bizarre thing is that the suggestion to "set nocompatible" is never accompanied by much concrete explanation of what the original setting does, or the dangers associated with changing it to"set nocompatible"  (https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1131)

Answer (score 2):

The traditional vi editor doesn't recognize the arrow keys (...afair). There are two solutions:

1. use vim instead of vi
2. use h, j, k and l to navigate (you can't navigate while editing on the traditional vi btw.)

Comment: This isn't true. Look for terminfo/termcap and libcurses based apps. I use vi since 1990 in Xenix, SCO Unix, AIX, old hpux, and others, and pure-vi from 80s already have support to terminfo/termcap mappings.

Comment: @james-wong well then I should rephrase my answer. To "pure vi under Ubuntu doesn't..."

Comment: ... and this was meant as a comment to @luciano

Answer (score 2):

On some systems, the `nocompatible` option is not available, or it may not fix the problem if a plugin breaks arrow key functionality. Here's a workaround...

Edit the `.exrc` file to include the following lines:

```
map! ^[OA ^[ka
map! ^[OB ^[ja
map! ^[OC ^[la
map! ^[OD ^[ha
```

Or, if the problem only exists in normal mode, you can change to `nmap` and skip the following `a`, as follows:

```
nmap! ^[OA ^[k
```

and so on.

Here's the key combinations needed to produce them (showing first one only):

```
map! <CTRL-V><Up-Arrow> <CTRL-V><ESC>ka
```

This escapes edit mode, moves in the wanted direction, and reenters edit mode. This is needed to overcome Vi reading the escape sequence as a sequence of literal <ESC><O><A>, etc.

Source: https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html

Answer (score 2):

For VI create or edit the file "~/.exrc" or VIM create or edit the file "~/.vimrc" set or add in the line.

```
set nocompatible
```

At the time of this writing there are commends on  the second most voted item that are wondering why their entry was not accepted. The reason is there are hosts that do not allow installing other editors. Even then vim sometimes has the same effects, so there is a bunch of usable info from the top two entries. I cannot comment however hopefully this clears up reasons why neither one is 100% correct 100% of the time.

Comment: tried some of the other answers here but for me (Ubuntu 19.10), editing the ~/.exrc file and adding the nocompatible worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because Vim received no (or wrong) information about the terminal you are using and therefore can't recognise the key presses correctly.

Since Vim tries to get this information from the `TERM` variable, this could be fixed by running

```bsh
export TERM=linux
```

before starting Vim.

This is similar to [Jasper Nuyens's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/932926/22949) about setting it to `xterm`. `xterm`, `xterm-color`, and `xterm-256color` relate to graphical terminal programs. [`linux` is the terminal type set in virtual consoles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43951/11938) and is worth trying if you're not in a graphical terminal, or if `xterm` was already set or otherwise not effective.

Answer (score 0):

On this machine I had to **`make sure`** that

```
set nocompatible
```

is the **`last entry in ~/.vimrc`**. Or at least one of the last entries, in particular no more plugin is loaded afterwards.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Ubuntu has omitted initialising envvar HOME for user root on my new 18.04 VPS. If that is the case, vi cannnot find the .vimrc file. The problem does not occur for normal users (in /home/).

To check the variable:

```
echo $HOME
```

If this results in a blank line, the variable is not set. The problem went away after

```
export HOME=/root
```

I moved the command into the /root/.bashrc file (I don't know where this is usually set).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying out `gvim`.

```
sudo apt install vim-gtk3
```

Gvim adds a graphical user interface on top of vim, and it does provide a proper cursor by default as well.