# Default vim usage in Ubuntu Bionic feels regressed from 17.10

Tags: vim, 18.04

Using Ubuntu Bionic (server image pre-GA), coming from Centos 7 (i.e. this may not be limited to just Bionic), I find that the vim editor has some very annoying defaults. How can I disable the following;

1. Auto-tab insertion in bash code when using if and pressing enter
2. Search with '/' requires one to press enter to go back to editing mode and pressing something else - like cursor right - swaps back to the original location instead of the location where one is at.

Both these do not feel like standard/default vim

Comment: [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Comment: @sudodus That's useful information in general, but if you're suggesting that this particular question should be closed this near to the release of 18.04, I don't think that's the case. Note that [we do not actually regard all Ubuntu+1 questions as off-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate). I don't think this question is about a bug, and the behavior it is asking about [is not going to change before the release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureFreeze).

Comment: @EliahKagan, I see your point, and I agree. (I did not vote for closing.)

Comment: I think this may be a bug or shortcoming in Bionic only, unrelated to VIM. ref discussion below. Also, does a feature freeze mean there are no more code changes, even if there are bugs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353911/hitting-arrow-keys-adds-characters-in-vi-editor)

Open `~/.vimrc` and add this;

`:set nocompatible`

This fixes all 3 issues to how they were in 17.10:

1. No more odd reactions when you search with '/'
2. No more odd tab/space inserts when editing
3. No more odd character inserts when using arrow keys in edit mode

I believe this to be a [bug in Ubuntu Bionic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/1767314), at least in the pre-GA release.

Comment: Logged as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/1767314