# Problem with `vi` editor

Tags: vi

When I open a new file using `vi` command:

```
vi <new file name>
```

After entering into file and typing the data I am getting the characters like `A`, `B`, `C`,  `D` when I use `<`, `>` arrows in order to move up the line or down the line

Comment: vi was an editor written back when terminals (or their keyboards) didn't all have arrow keys so h-j-k-l keys performed the movement options. `vi` is smaller so is installed by default; most of us grab `vim` even if we don't use vim's extra features - because we aren't still in the 70s or early 80s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hitting arrow keys adds characters in vi editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353911/hitting-arrow-keys-adds-characters-in-vi-editor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative way to solve this is by creating a vimrc file:

```
# vi ~/.vimrc
```

And adding the following line in it:

```
set nocompatible
```

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by installing `vim`:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Comment: Is there any other way to overcome this ?

Comment: forget about vi, use vim. that's it.