# Mouse scroll doesn't work in WSL in Vi/Vim editor

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, lts, vim, vi

I have Windows 11 with WSL and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. When I open any program in the Vi/Vim editor, I can't scroll up or down using the mouse. Any solution for it?

I tried to add `set mouse=a` in `.vimrc`. The scroll then worked, but it gave another problem. With that in place, I can't select texts by the normal way of clicking on mouse and paste it somewhere else in the terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hitting arrow keys adds characters in vi editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353911/hitting-arrow-keys-adds-characters-in-vi-editor)

Comment: (  Don't forget `vi` was written back in the days when very few terminals actually had arrow keys...  )

Comment: Hi, I tried the solutions given from the link given by muru. I tried to add set nocompatible in the vimrc and also tried to install new vim editor, still doesn't work. Also. it doesn't work in vim

Comment: I see a deleted answer from you on this.  Did `set mouse=a` not work after all?  Regardless, you should edit the question to include that as something you've tried. Thanks!